# Text viewer/editor to show text in columns to maximise visible content on a single screen?

Tags: text-editors, viewer

Hopefully this image illustrates what I'm after to help view a long log file:
[image: column sketch].

Preferably a text editor, but any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are you asking for a text editor that, instead of creating a large, vertical scroll region, wraps text to a "new page", that is displayed to the right of the last one?

Comment: @RLH: Yes, this is what I'm after.

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this in Word, let me see what it's called; then we can look for other editors with the feature.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Word can do this with it's 'columns' feature.